# three20 TTTableView didSelectObject not beeing called

Tags: iphone, three20

I populated data in my TTTableViewController with subclass of TTSectionedDataSource filled with TTTableTextItem.

```
 [items addObject:[TTTableTextItem itemWithText:title URL:@"tt://page"]
```

The TTTableViewController can display without any problem. But when I click the cell, it will be selected with blue color but no further action.

Then I implement didSelectObject and try to figure out what's happen:

```
- (void) didSelectObject:(id)object atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"%@",@"hahaha");
}
```

But no log shows up, this method won't be called. Help, please.

Updated:

Finally, I found the problem. My TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate didn't init properly.

```
- (id<UITableViewDelegate>) createDelegate {

    return [[[TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate alloc] init] autorelease];

}
```

It shoule be :

```
- (id<TTTableViewDelegate>) createDelegate {

    TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate *delegate = [[TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate alloc] initWithController:self];

    return [delegate autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `didSelectObject` method is only called when URL is set to `nil` in your `TTTableTextItem`, since it specifies that you want to handle the click yourself.  Try setting it `nil` and see if your `didSelectObject` gets called.  But if you don't want any specific action being done by clicking on the item besides opening up a new ViewController, you shouldn't need to override the method.  Just make sure that your @"tt://page" actually points to something in your `TTURLMap`

Comment: Hi Andrew, it's getting worse when I set the URL as nil. There is no response When I click the cell. It cannot be selected now.

Comment: I'd need to see more code.  Can you paste the contents of your data source and view controller?

Comment: Please see my update. it's the TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate.

Comment: Ah glad you found the answer, you should add it as an answer and mark it as answered :)